# CSS line and dot on same level with :after

Tags: html, css

I need one class and one class only to have a line and a dot. They should be line up one after another. So I try `:after`.

The issue I have is the dot is drops down to the next line. Please give me a hand to move the dot up and line up right after the line.

```css
.wrapper {
border-top: 4px solid red;
width: 90px;
}
.wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
 
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want to achieve. The position of the ball is done via `position: absolute` and calculating it from the left side of the `border-top`.

That results in `left: calc(100% - 5px);`, I made it a green ball to distinguish it from the bar.

Read more about [positioning elements at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning).

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 4px solid red;
  width: 90px;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: calc(100% - 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

</div>
```

---

Comment: Hi Roy, Thank you very much for sharing, that works!